# XNA How to make an object invisible

Tags: c#, xna, collision, visible

I'm making a 2D Shooter game in XNA. I had been working on the shooting speed of the player (Every how often can the player shoot another bullet) and made it so that the player can only shoot again once the previous bullet has traveled a certain distance like so:

```
if (this.bulletList[0].BULLETS[(this.bulletList[0].BULLETS.Count) - 1].X >= Pos.X + attackSpeed)
                canShoot = true;
```

Where bulletList is the available Projectiles the player can shoot, BULLETS is the List of Bullets already shot, and attackSpeed is the rate in which the bullets should be shot, or simply put: the distance the bullet has to travel until another bullet can be shot.

Now I've been working on Collisions. My method was to dispose of a bullet after it hits a target like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < player.BULLETLIST[0].BULLETS.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CollisionManager.PlayerBulletOnBot(player.BULLETLIST[0].BULLETS[i], bot))
                player.BULLETLIST[0].BULLETS.RemoveAt(i);
        }
```

Problem is, if the bullet has been removed upon hitting a target, I can no longer ask if that bullet has passed the given distance for another bullet to be shot.
To solve that, I'd like the bullet to turn **invisible** upon hit, and afterwards it'll be disposed of in another function that's already been made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply have a `Visible` flag for a `Bullet` instance:

```
class Bullet {
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}
```

When it hits.. make it invisible:

```
// ... hit
bulletInstace.Visible = false;
```

Then check before drawing it:

```
if (bulletInstance.Visible)
    drawBullet(bullet);
```

If it isn't visible, your drawing code should just skip over it.

Comment: A bullet only needs to be drawn once. Once its there I can tweak it's position in any way I want. It doesn't get re-drawn in a different position, therefore I can't use that flag. That is why I think making the object transparents or invisible should work.

Comment: Drawn once? .. per frame correct? That flag lets you skip over it the next frame..

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't draw something once in XNA and simply move it each frame. That's just not how the framework works. Simon's right, you're going to want a Visible property that you alter, and only draw the bullet based on this.

Comment: @Villager The `Draw` method is called once per frame. If you check this `Visible` flag before the bullets are drawn in the `Draw` method.. then you can skip over them that frame (and into the future). Effectively making them invisible until they actually die.

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll look for that part in the code.

Comment: Well I've found exactly what you've suggested, but the problem is, the list called BULLETS is List<Vector2> rather than a list of projectiles.

Comment: That isn't a problem.. you should wrap the vectors in a `Bullet` instance. That way you can attach even more properties on to them in future.

Answer (score 0):

When you draw an object using `spriteBatch.Draw(...)` you have to select a color for the sprite itself.

We all know that the color is a mixture of "red, green and blue" values (or rgb). What not many people know is that, at least in XNA, there is a fourth value called alpha.

The alpha value indicates the transparency of your object, meaning that if you use it like the code below, your object will be half invisible (or half visible).

```
spriteBatch.Draw(..., Color.White * 0,5f,...);
```

You can play with that :)

Check a little more [here](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/97337/580842.aspx), on the old XNA forums.

Answer (score 0):

You need rate of fire (`rof`) property that you increase to some `maxRof` value when you hold down button. and when rof is equal to maxrof then you add bullet to a list of bullets (and reset `rof` to 0).

Do not make it invisible, remove it from list. Every instance of bullet should have "Active" property set to true on fire. (when you fire a bullet, add it to list) And when collsition happened set this property to false. pseudo code as example:

UPDATE

```
for each bullet in bullets
  -- update bullet position
  -- check collision if happened if yes then set Active to false
end for

bullets.removeall(function(c) NOT(c.active));
```

DRAW

```
for each bullet in bullets.findall(function(c) c.active)
  -- draw your bullets
end for
```

Comment: Why shouldn't he make the bullets invisible. It's easier. But of course this can be used too.

Comment: invisible means that bullet is hidden, but update function is still calculating position and other parameters. is his example he need that to calculate position and distance... but if using ROF he don't need that so he could simply dispose that bullet after collision.

Comment: it's only calculating until it hits a certain distance(in Villager's code). He can then make his collision `&& (player.BULLETLIST[0].BULLETS[i].Visible == false)`
  But that's just an option, it's great to see other people their answers for an other view on a subject.